# Searching A File For Specific Names in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm a relatively new programmer and I'm working on a school project. Right now what I'm trying to do is read through a file and get it to check if two characters interact(i.e they appear on the same line).

Right now I haven't too much done and I'm really asking more for ideas rather than code. How would one go about doing something like this? I had a few ideas but none of them actually worked in practise so as of now, this is all I really have done and working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 struct Characters{

    char names[65][50]; //This is the names array
    char compnames[65][50]; //This is a duplicate to compare the arrays of characters
    int relations;

};


void NameFun();

int main(){

    NameFun();
}

void NameFun(){

    int i=0, choice;
    struct Characters c;

    FILE *fp = NULL; 
    fp = fopen("MisNames.txt", "r"); 

    for(i=0; i<65; i++){

        fgets(c.names[i], sizeof(c.names[i]), fp); //Gets each name and stores it as an element of an array
        strcpy(c.compnames[i], c.names[i]); //For the duplicate, copying the elements
    }


    /*The rest of this was for testing purposes and has no real relevance
    printf("What number name would you like to know about?\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    choice = choice--;

    printf("\t\t\t%s\n\n", c.names[choice]);
    fclose(fp);
}*/
```

Comment: Shouldn't `choice = choice--;` be just `choice--;` ?

Comment: You should `return 0;` as you've defined main function as it returns an int value.

Comment: I suppose it should now that I actually look at it but that was just for testing, it's not overly important!

Comment: @Varaquilex: `int` for main is needed, `return 0` at the end optional per standard.

Comment: Always check how much you really read.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't really understand what you mean..

Comment: Please rewrite your inputs and outputs. Your request is contradictory. (Elaborate)

Comment: `scanf` returns how many patterns were matched. Never assume all (or none) were matched without checking.

Comment: @Deduplicator exactly my point.